# What is the best place to find software development conference listings?

Tags: java, c++, tdd, agile, conference

I am interested in an array of software ideas and use more than one language, is there somewhere that concisely lists software development conferences year by year?  I'd like to know what options are out there for this year and searching by ideology/language isn't practical in my opinion to get an overall.

Some ideologies/languages that interest me (but open to others):

TDD (with various languages, not just Java)
Agile (w/Scrum, Kanban)
Java
C++
.NET/C#
Development Tools (IDE, Debuggers, etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a listing but I use http://www.infoq.com/ to watch videos of past conferences.

Answer (score 1):

[ConfRadar](http://confradar.com/) is a really nice to tool to find out about conferences. I am sure you'll find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just a list of conferences which I see useful http://lanyrd.com/topics/software-development/

Comment: Please provide the useful information of the link in your answer because once the link dies, your answer becomes useless. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Plancast just launched an O'Reilly section. Not exactly what you're looking for, but might be useful.

http://plancast.com/oreilly